# query in django

Tags: python, django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model)

    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image,blank=Trues')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and I have list of usernames from UserProfile and want to get their emails, something like

```
select email from UserProfile where username=given_name
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: But that SQL query isn't what you want, is it? You want `where username in (list, of, names)`, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup and [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method.  But you have to filter the `User` model instead of `UserProfile`:

```
usernames = ['john', 'ivan']
emails = User.objects.filter(username__in=usernames) \
                     .values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Comment: why from User, and not from UserProfile?

Comment: Because both `username` and `email` fields are from the `User` model.